# Queue inside microservice

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, microservices

Let's imagine we want to clean sheep in the herd in such a way, that each sheep can be cleaned once at a time - other cleaning tasks for this sheep should be queued.
We also have a bunch of shepherds, which can clean multiple sheep at a time.
Number of sheep is very big and variable (they die and are born....).
Requests to clean a sheep are random and are made quite often.

In this approach shepherd is a microservice instance.

What architecture should be used to:

- make sure that sheep is cleaned only once at the same time
- one shepherd can clean multiple sheep at a time
- the same sheep is not cleaned by multiple shepherds at the same time
- sheep is automatically cleaned again and again, if there were multiple clean task send for the same sheep

Solutions so far:

1. In memory queue of each shepherd - doesn't work - multiple shepherds can clean the same sheep
2. External queue like RabbitMQ - would force me to create separate queue for each sheep - with variable number of sheep it would be impossible to mantain

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are we talking about actual animal cleaning software here, or are the sheep in your question an abstraction of something else? If so, then you should pose your question without using analogy - it causes confusion.... ;)

Comment: The shepherds have a locker, let's call it the sheep cleaning locker. The locker contains a bunch of spoons, each of which have a different sheep's name written on it. If shepherd-1 gets a sheep-445 cleaning task of his queue then he opens the locker and gets the spoon with sheep-445 written on it. When he has finished cleaning sheep-445, he puts the spoon back into the locker. If shepherd-2 gets a sheep-445 cleaning task before shepherd-1 has finished cleaning sheep-445 he opens the locker and cannot find the sheep-445 spoon. So he discards the task and moves onto the next one.

Comment: the software is about creating containers based on some rules, which are hard to express easily, hence analogy. External locking service means we still needs queue somewhere. Getting a task from queue, and noack it (putting it again to the end) is queue antipattern